# How to pass text field of inputed data to url on swift

Tags: ios, swift, url, textfield

I've created two `UITextField`

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtUsername: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtUserpassword: UITextField!
```

and make username and password to store the data

```
let username = txtUsername.text
let userpassword = txtUserpassword.text
```

Also, pass the data to URL

```
let urlAsString = "http://lifewinner2015.dlinkddns.com/SERVER/user?function=login&username=\(username)&password=\(userpassword)"
```

but the `\(username)` and `\(user password)` may be error, Xcode can not run this.

Can help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Note that each URL component needs to be escaped properly. Escaping is error prone and easy to get wrong.

Thus, you should use `NSURLComponents` to create a URL which also automatically escapes the different components of an URL for you:

```
let urlString = "http://lifewinner2015.dlinkddns.com/SERVER/user"
```

Note: the above URL also consists of several components which may require escaping. IFF you are sure for the given string literal you don't need escaping, you can try to set  the URL string as above. Otherwise set each component separately.

```
guard let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: urlString) else {
    throw MyError.CouldNotCreateURLFromString(string: urlString)
}
```

Then create the url query component:

```
let queryItems: [NSURLQueryItem] = [
    NSURLQueryItem(name: "function", value: "login"),
    NSURLQueryItem(name: "username", value: username),
    NSURLQueryItem(name: "password", value: userpassword)
]
```

and assign it the url components object:

```
urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems
```

Obtaining the URL should not throw now, but anyway:

```
guard let url = urlComponents.URL else {
    throw MyError.CouldNotCreateURL
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This code helped to come out of an issue i was struggling for 3 days. Happy Coding...!!!